# Center of a convex set

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

Let $A$ be a compact convex set and define the diameter of $A$ as $$\max_{x,y \in A} \| x - y \| < 2 \epsilon$$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Is it true that there exists a point $z\in A$ such that $\|k-z\| < \epsilon$ for all $k \in A$?

Comment: When testing claims, simple examples are good. The simplest examples of convex sets are plane polygons; try a few of them to see if the statement is plausible.

Comment: It might help to note that in two dimensions, what you are computing is ultimately the radius of the [circumscribed circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle) for the convex set. As a simple counterexample, consider what happens for an equilateral triangle.